# Firefox extension: Getting exception "Permission denied to access property href" for code running in sandbox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am running the attached code as my firefox extension.
Currently all the extension does is alerting the current location of the page (and iframes) the browser is currently on. For some reason, in some cases I get the following exception when trying to alert the location:

> Permission denied to access property href

Unfortunately I can't understand the exact scenario or page the code works and where it throws the exception.
Did anybody encountered this ?
Thanks !

Here is the browser.xul file content (without the HTML tags):

```
setTimeout(function() {
        var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
        if (appcontent) {
                appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (aEvent) {
                var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
                if (!(doc instanceof HTMLDocument)) {
                    // Validation.
                    return;
                }

                var sandbox = new Components.utils.Sandbox(doc.defaultView, {
                    'sandboxPrototype': doc.defaultView,
                    'wantXrays': true
                });

                sandbox.window = doc.defaultView;
                sandbox.document = doc.defaultView.document;            
                sandbox.__proto__ = doc.defaultView;
                sandbox.unsafeWindow = doc.defaultView.wrappedJSObject;
                var strCode = "try { alert(window.location.href); } catch(e1) {alert(e1.message);}";
                Components.utils.evalInSandbox(strCode, sandbox, "1.8");
            }, true);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: The exception must be due to a cross origin violation.

Comment: Yeah, as @paa said, the exception must me a cross origin violation. However, as the principal of the box is set up in a way that the sandbox should always have the same principal (origin) of the doc/window it is evaluated on, this is still curious. Can you provide any example URIs of tabs where this happens and/or URIs of windows where this happens (e.g. log/alter doc.defaultView.location directly from your chrome code)? Also, can you at detail a bit at what you're trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: As @nmaier said there shouldn't be a cross origin violation and that's the true mystery here.  
The general idea of the extension is that I read the code evaluated dynamically (not shown in the code snippet I posted) and in that code I want to check the current location before I do certain actions.  
Since this is an error I get from my users, unfortunately, I don't have specific URIs this happens to them to provide you.  
I was wondering if you have any ideas on how to find a scenario which might cause this exception so I could recreate it and debug.

Comment: If I had to guess (and it seems you want me to ;), I'd bet on non-standard principals, such as about: or even chrome:?, or webapp principals. Also, I just remembered you shouldn't set `__proto__` on the Sandbox: https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/commit/c10f6f14895935b927575a1058100799b20ad720

Comment: PS: It shouldn't be necessary (or might even be a problem) to set `sb.window`. This is already implied by `sandboxPrototype` and the fact that `window.window === window`. Same for `sb.document`